# Computing statistical Significance of Rank Order Question

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures, ranking, ranks, friedman-test

In my questionnaire, I have a rank order question concerning three different videos. Each respondent must rank each of the videos either on position 1, 2 or 3. All respondents are in the same group (the questionnaire is in a repeated measure design). While analyzing the results, I found that one video was rated much more often at the first position than others. I am now planning to compute whether or not this difference is statistically significant.

My approach was to first calculate a mean score for each video (mean scores were about 1.5, 2 and 2.5 for the three different videos with n=33). Next, I planned to analyze whether the differences between the means were significant by using a Friedman-Test.

My question is now: Is this approach correct? Am I allowed to use the Friedman Test for analyzation even though the three values are highly dependent to each other (since it is a rank order, if I rank the first video with rank 1, the others can only be rated as 2 or 3 and are therefore dependent on the first answer)? Do you know of any other, better approaches to calculate whether differences are significant?